# Check if a cell in csv only contains a value

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a csv of 2 columns A and B. A contains words and B contains the word type. I want to append a count that increases when the cell contains either "." or "?" or "!". However they must only contain one "." or one "?" or one "!". It shouldn't increase when the cell contains "..." or "!!!???!"

I have created the code:

```
from csv import writer
from csv import reader

sentence_number = 1

with open('input.csv', 'r') as read_obj,\
    open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        
        for row in csv_reader:
            if str(row[0])== "." or str(row[0])=="?" or str(row[0]) == "!":
                sentence_number = sentence_number + 1 
            
            row.append(sentence_number)
            
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Edit: The original csv file is

```
This;Adverb
flower;Noun
is;Verb
pretty;Adjective
.;Punctuation
I;Pronoun
like;Verb
flowers;Noun
!;Punctuation
```

However it gives rows as

```
This;Adverb,1
flower;Noun,1
is;Verb,1
pretty;Adjective,1
.;Punctuation,1
I;Pronoun,1
like;Verb,1
flowers;Noun,1
!;Punctuation,1
```

Expected cvs outcome is:

```
This;Adverb;1
flower;Noun;1
is;Verb;1
pretty;Adjective;1
.;Punctuation;1
I;Pronoun;2
like;Verb;2
flowers;Noun;2
!;Punctuation;2
```

Basically I want to recognize which sentence a word belongs to, i.e. "This" belongs to sentence 1. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Would you mind showing the content of the file you are using? That way we can see the format and have a bit more of information.

Comment: Hi@LucasGarcíadeViedmaPérez I have added an edit. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @StevenRumbalski I tried `open('ner-corpus-output.csv', 'w', newline='',delimiter=';')` and `open('ner-corpus-output.csv', 'w', newline='',sep=';')`but it throws error `'delimiter' is an invalid keyword argument for open()
`

Comment: You need to give that argument to `reader(read_obj, sep=';')` and `writer(write_obj, sep=';')`, not to the `open()` method.

Comment: Hi @LouisCloete it still throws `'sep' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
`

Comment: Ah, I see the `csv` module called it `delimiter`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Answer (score 1):

Once you have determined the file you want to read, you read it with this line:

```
csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
```

However, reader doesn't return a string, but an object of this type:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x000002145A5B71C0>
```

The problem occurs because you expect this line:

```
for row in csv_reader:
```

to iterate over the object storing in "row" a string with the content of each row. But what it actually stores is an array with the string inside, such as:

```
["This;Adverb"]
```

To solve this, you simply need to add another [0] when checking for the punctuation signs.

Besides that, i noticed another error that led to the concatenation of the number with a "," instead of a ";", which was due to `row.append(sentence_number)`, so i swapped it with `row += ";" + str(sentence_number)`.

Here's the code with the changes, i hope it helps:

```
from csv import writer
from csv import reader

sentence_number = 1

with open('a.txt', 'r') as read_obj, \
    open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:

    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    csv_writer = writer(write_obj)

    for row in csv_reader:

        row = row[0]
        row += ";" + str(sentence_number)

        if row[0] == "." or row[0] == "?" or row[0] == "!":
            sentence_number = sentence_number + 1

        csv_writer.writerow([row])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the detailed explanation! It works :)

Comment: Hi! Yes I noticed that the writer will take the row as a list of characters. It was my bad. Thank you :)